# Metadata of the current played song on android

Tags: java, android, metadata, mp3

Hi stackers im working on a project and i'm having some troubles on getting the metadata of the current played song. The idea is to get the next items:
title, album, artist, genre, date, year. I've been testing the MetadataRetriever method that I've found on several examples here on StackOverflow, also the intent.getStringExtra("Key"), and finally trying to get the data from a bundle, but anything gaves me all the data I need. I usually get nulls. Any idea? But the most important is that the metadata have to come from the actual song played. 
Thanks in advance.

```
package com.example.andres.metadataextract;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    //ImageView album_art;
    String title, album, artist, genre, fecha, address, path, length;
    Long duration;
    File archivo;

    //MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriver;

    //byte[] art;
    //public static final String SERVICECMD = "com.android.music.musicservicecommand";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        IntentFilter iF = new IntentFilter();
        iF.addAction("com.android.music.metachanged");
        iF.addAction("com.android.music.playstatechanged");
        iF.addAction("com.android.music.playbackcomplete");
        iF.addAction("com.android.music.queuechanged");
        iF.addAction("com.android.music.metachanged");
        iF.addAction("com.htc.music.metachanged");
        iF.addAction("fm.last.android.metachanged");
        iF.addAction("com.sec.android.app.music.metachanged");
        iF.addAction("com.nullsoft.winamp.metachanged");
        iF.addAction("com.amazon.mp3.metachanged");
        iF.addAction("com.miui.player.metachanged");
        iF.addAction("com.real.IMP.metachanged");
        iF.addAction("com.sonyericsson.music.metachanged");
        iF.addAction("com.rdio.android.metachanged");
        iF.addAction("com.samsung.sec.android.MusicPlayer.metachanged");
        iF.addAction("com.andrew.apollo.metachanged");
        iF.addAction("com.meizu.media.music");
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, iF);
        //metaRetriver = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //metaRetriver.setDataSource(address);
            //String action = intent.getAction();
            //String cmd = intent.getStringExtra("command");
            //Log.v("tag ", action + " / " + cmd);
            //artist = intent.getStringExtra("artist");
            //album = intent.getStringExtra("album");
            //title = intent.getStringExtra("track");
            //address = intent.getStringExtra("address");
            //archivo = new File(direccion);

            //I can get the values of those 3 items
            Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
            title = intent.getStringExtra("track");
            album = intent.getStringExtra("album");
            artist= intent.getStringExtra("artist");

            //Cant get the values of those others
            genre= intent.getStringExtra("genre");
            fecha= extra.getString("date");
            duration= (intent.getLongExtra(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION,1000));
            address = extra.getString("address");

            //album = (metaRetriver.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM));
            //artist = (metaRetriver.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST));
            //genre = (metaRetriver.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_GENRE));
            //fecha = (metaRetriver.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DATE));
            //duration = (metaRetriver.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION));


            //Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            //        MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            //        null,
            //        null,
            //        null,
            //        MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC");

            //art = metaRetriver.getEmbeddedPicture();
            //Bitmap songImage = BitmapFactory
            //        .decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length);
            //album_art.setImageBitmap(songImage);
            try {

                //while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                //    title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
                // Whatever else you need
                // }
                //title = (metaRetriver.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE));
                //album = (metaRetriver.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM));
                //artist = (metaRetriver.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST));
                //genre = (metaRetriver.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_GENRE));
                //fecha = (metaRetriver.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DATE));
                //duration = (metaRetriver.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                //album_art.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                //title = ("Unknown Title");
                //album = ("Unknown Album");
                //artist = ("Unknown Artist");
                //genre = ("Unknown Genre");
                //fecha = ("Unknown Date");
                //duration = ("Unknown Duration");

            }

            String all = "Title:"+ title +"\n Album:" + album + "\n Artist:" + artist + "\n Genre:" + genre
                    + "\n Fecha:" + fecha + "\n Duration:" + duration + "\n Address:" + address + "\n lenght:" + length + "\n Path:" + path;
            //Log.v("yossi", extra.toString());
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, all, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, extra.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, all, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    };
}
```

Comment: can you post some code on what you did?

Comment: Yes I can but its just a draft and have many lines commented. Fixing a bit the code and updating the question. Thanks for your interest :D

Comment: I also encountered same problem sometime before.But in my case there was no required metadata in some of the media file. Thus i was encountering null problem.  What i did was see if it is null and then categorized it under Unknown Artist/Album... categories.

Comment: I'm testing it with files that have all the metadata fields. I can get some items but I really want to get the others in order to make the app more complete.